# Extracting audio from video command fails for some videos

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using below FFmpeg command for extracting audio from video-

> String[]         complexCommand = new String[]{"-y","-ss", "" +
>   startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i",
>   inputFileAbsolutePath, "-vn", "-ar", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-b:a",
>   "256k", "-f", "mp3", outputFileAbsolutePath};

It works fine in my device but through analytics I came to know that its failing for many users or for many videos.I failed to understand whats wrong with the command and why its failing many times?

Comment: inputFileAbsolutePath is correct as its working for other commands and i am checking it before sending to command

Comment: Need log from a failed execution to really tell. One possibility is that input audio stream is malformed or has an exotic codec, although if your app is mass-market, unlikely.

Comment: @pskink I am using FFMpeg

Comment: @Gyan Is the command correct for extracting audio from video?

Comment: It'll work, if you need output to be uniformly MP3.